# Check if std::list iterator is at end without access to the container

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, stdlist

In a function, I work with a `std::list<Type>::const_iterator`. I don't have access to the container.

**Is there a way to check if the iterator point to an accessible element (i.e. the iterator is not at the end of the container) ?**

*Note: I use C++11 (I don't want solution for C++ >= 14)*

Comment: you can put a sentinal value at the end of the list

Comment: You had better at least have the limits of the container, even if you don't have the container itself. I.e. you had better have at least the `end()` iterator, which not only solves your problem, it also likely addresses what is probably an unspoken XY problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

An iterator devoid of context is useless. Usually you will have a *pair* of iterators, denoting the range of interest.